# How can we integrate with Facebook from Server side Java code?

Tags: java, facebook, google-app-engine, facebook-graph-api, server-side

I want to use Google Cloud **App Engine (Java)** to integrate with Facebook from **Server side**.

I understand that the following Web SDKs are available which can be potentially used:

1. **Javascipt SDK** (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript)
2. **PHP SDK** (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php)

But I can't find any native server side Java SDK for Facebook.

Or we can directly use Facebook **Graph API**:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api

What would be the best way to implement this?

Comment: Not sure have you gone thru this link, provide detailed documentation for FB integration http://restfb.com/

Answer (score 0):

Further investigation on the lead provided by @mhasan, found the following third-party Java SDKs have been acknowledged (Not endorsed or recommended) by Facebook:

[Java (Spring)](http://www.springsource.org/spring-social/) by Spring Social

[Java (Blackberry)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/facebook-bb-sdk/) by RIM

[Kinvey](http://www.kinvey.com/facebook-open-graph-for-mobile-apps) by Kinvey

[RestFB](http://restfb.com/) by Mark Allen